# Join relation query for an Excel File

Tags: laravel

Hello i try to display some values from my Eloquent model "Licencies" who are in others tables in relation with an id but i get

> Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in on clause is
>   ambiguous

I'm not sure to make the join method correctly , someone could help me ?

Here my query :

```
 $licencies = Licencies::where('lb_assurance' , '=' , 'Lafont')
            ->leftJoin('activite_licencie' , 'id' , '=' , 'licencie.activite_licencie_id')
            ->leftJoin('saisons' , 'id' , '=' , 'licencie.saison_id')
            ->leftJoin('pays' , 'id' , '=' , 'licencie.pays_naissance_id')
            ->leftJoin('type_licence' , 'id' , '=' , 'licencie.type_licence_id')
            ->leftJoin('structures' , 'id' , '=' , 'licencie.structure.id')
            ->select('num_licence' , 'lb_nom' , 'lb_prenom' , 'dt_naissance' , 'lb_surclassement' , 'lb_assurance' , 'cd_dept_naissance' , 'activite_licencie.lb_activite' , 'saisons.lb_saison' , 'pays.fr' , 'type_licence.lb_type' , 'structures.nom_structure' )->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are column name id in all the related tables so mysql does not know which id you are referring to. To resolve this issue prepend the ids with their respective table names. eg. **'structures.id'**

```
->leftJoin('structures' , 'structures.id' , '=' , 'licencie.structure.id')
```

Comment: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'licencie.structure.id' in 'on clause'

Comment: you are welcome. you can accept the answer if it works for you.